# Ionic 3 - native keyboard plugin returning errors/warnings

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3, cordova-plugins, ionic-native

I've made an Ionic 3 app and got stuck while trying to implement the native keyboard plugin. None of the already existing topics on this issue seemed to work. So...what I did following the official docs https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/keyboard/:
1.CLI: `ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard`
2.CLI: `npm install --save @ionic-native/keyboard`
3. Added the Keyboard in the app.module.ts providers section
4. tried to use it as per documentation

```
import { Keyboard } from '@ionic-native/keyboard';

constructor(private keyboard: Keyboard) { 
   this.keyboard.show();
}
```

Also, I've used the `ionic cordova run browser` command and still receive all sorts of warnings / errors.

From what I've seen, i tend to belive that the respective plugin's current version is updated for Ionic v4 beta (latest at the moment).

If anyone has a working solutions for this case, please share it!
Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Trying running in your real device i.e android/ios

```
ionic cordova build android/ios
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

some of cordova plugins will not work in the browser you have to run it on an emulator or real device